# How to have a common top bar across the application?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I have an application that I am working on. I need the application to have a common top navigation bar across all the screens. Like so: 
[image]

I need to do this because as you can see, the buttons on the bar are global in nature and aren't screen specific.

Comment: create top bar in root view controller. have a uiview below it. and add all other views in that subview below top bar.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom view similar to navigationbar in your app delegate class and add this custom view at the top of application window and handle all action by declaring method in app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

- Here parent and child Class come into picture.
- If you want to make a navigation Bar which will be common throughout the application,1st create a parent class ,on which we have to design all our design part like navigationBar color ,title view etc.
- Create a parent class  of type UIViewController and write design things in ViewDidLoad method.

> @interface ParentViewController : UIViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar-logo.jpg"];
    UIImageView *titleLogo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logoImage];
    titleLogo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLogo;
}
```

- Create all ViewControllers of type ParentViewController in which you want this 
  design .

> ```
> @interface ChildViewController1 : ParentViewController
>
> @interface ChildViewController2 : ParentViewController
> ```